# CALayer doesn't redraw on property update

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-animation

I'm attempting to customize a UIPageControl by adding borders around the dots. My code compiles and runs fine, but the changes don't seem to be taking effect.

```
for pageIndicator in pageControl.subviews {
    if let layer = pageIndicator.layer {
        layer.borderWidth = 3.0
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        layer.cornerRadius = 1.5
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? Do I need to tell iOS to redraw the layer somehow?

Comment: This is not your control to customize. If you want something that acts like a UIPageControl but has borders around the dots, you really should build it yourself.

Comment: try calling `layer.setNeedsDisplay()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it seems the popular opinion is that it's simply not a good idea to customize `UIPageControl` as I intended. Several other SO answers recommended a library called [SMPageControl](https://github.com/Spaceman-Labs/SMPageControl) which supports custom images and views as page indicators.